# Best way to write new Pig script and debug it along

Tags: apache-pig

I usually find it difficult to locate the bug in Pig script, so I don't write bunch of lines and then test them.

While writing a new pig script, I usually keep my grunt shell open and keep executing every statement, finding describe and explain along the way. This gives me idea of what current relation looks like and how to extract/add fields from/in that relation. But this is time consuming, as pig executes from start for Nth statement, and then again for N+1th statement.

I wanted to know how people usually write a new script and debug/execute along the way.
Is there a way where Pig grunt shell simply executes last statement instead of executing from start?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? Would be great if you can share some tips on how you are going about this now...

Comment: @Phani, no I did not find anything better than my current approach. Debug it alongside on grunt shell after every block of new lines - this executes the script from scratch.

I usually slice the actual data to very small data set during development, so the script run time is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

We can't debug while it is running. Pig runs from first command whenever we start the script. That is why we call it as data flow language. It runs every statement sequentially.

Comment: thanks. I want to know what people (read experts) do when they start writing new pig code or update existing pig code.